# $.ajax response is empty

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have seen other related questions but could not find an exact match to my problem on SO. Trying to get JSON back from worldweatheronline.com using $.ajax and keep getting empty response. In Fiddler however, I see a proper response each time, only in the browser, it seems to be empty (looked up using Firebug and alert statements). Using .ajax method as I want to parse the JSON when response is available.

Below is the code snippet, raw request and raw response.

```
            var jsonxhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=55122&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=<somekey>',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (json) {
                alert('request success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert('request error');
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                //alert('request complete');
                try {
                    var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(jsonxhr.responseText);
                    //alert('success parsing');
                    alert('test' + jsonxhr.responseText + 'test');
                    alert('headers ' + jsonxhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    //alert(parsedJson.data.weather.tempMaxF.toString());
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert("error parsing");
                }
            }
        });
```

> Raw request

GET http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=55122&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=somekey HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: free.worldweatheronline.com

> Raw response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2011 04:20:46 GMT
Content-Length: 2712

{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "100", "humidity": "50", "observation_time": "03:50 AM", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1017", "temp_C": "-3", "temp_F": "26", "visibility": "16", "weatherCode": "122",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Overcast" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "N", "winddirDegree": "10", "windspeedKmph": "11", "windspeedMiles": "7" } ],  "request": [ {"query": "55122", "type": "Zipcode" } ],  "weather": [ {"date": "2011-12-27", "precipMM": "0.0", "tempMaxC": "2", "tempMaxF": "35", "tempMinC": "-4", "tempMinF": "24", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "NNW", "winddirDegree": "343", "winddirection": "NNW", "windspeedKmph": "28", "windspeedMiles": "18" }, {"date": "2011-12-28", "precipMM": "0.0", "tempMaxC": "2", "tempMaxF": "36", "tempMinC": "-6", "tempMinF": "22", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "SW", "winddirDegree": "220", "winddirection": "SW", "windspeedKmph": "17", "windspeedMiles": "11" }, {"date": "2011-12-29", "precipMM": "0.3", "tempMaxC": "4", "tempMaxF": "39", "tempMinC": "-1", "tempMinF": "30", "weatherCode": "116",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "WSW", "winddirDegree": "257", "winddirection": "WSW", "windspeedKmph": "20", "windspeedMiles": "13" }, {"date": "2011-12-30", "precipMM": "0.3", "tempMaxC": "1", "tempMaxF": "35", "tempMinC": "-1", "tempMinF": "30", "weatherCode": "119",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Cloudy" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "SW", "winddirDegree": "228", "winddirection": "SW", "windspeedKmph": "18", "windspeedMiles": "11" }, {"date": "2011-12-31", "precipMM": "0.7", "tempMaxC": "4", "tempMaxF": "39", "tempMinC": "0", "tempMinF": "32", "weatherCode": "122",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Overcast" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "W", "winddirDegree": "268", "winddirection": "W", "windspeedKmph": "21", "windspeedMiles": "13" } ] }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `jsonp` isn't really AJAX.  Because of this, the `xhr` object does not have everything you might expect to see in a real AJAX call.  You should use the data which is passed to the `success` callback instead.

Comment: I agree. The data that is passed into the success callback contains parsed json, so you wont need to use `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that did fix it and I was able to parse. I didn't understand though what you meant by "jsonp isn't really AJAX", @James Montagne. I thought jsonp is also AJAX but used for inter-domain calls... Now I don't know why, but my request only works when I have data type as 'jsonp' and it fails when I try 'json'. Any light on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP .  JSONP uses scripts to get around the fact that AJAX can't make cross-domain calls.  It's missing the X in AJAX, there is no XML involved.  XMLHttpRequest is not used.